# R: Transpose variables in column into row by date

Tags: r

[Solution] I found my own solution to the problem.

```
  require(data.table)
  dt <- data.table(dataframe)
  newdt<-dt[, number := 1:.N, by = Date] 
  data<-as.data.frame(newdt)

data_wide <- reshape(newdt, direction="wide", idvar = "Date", timevar =   "number")

data_wide

6/26/2015   209.3     230.2     80.4     s2
6/27/2015   209.1     227.2     239.2    s2
```

Edit 2: I think that the solution provided by others would work if I can figure out how to create a new column in my original dataframe that **labels** the number of the rows (or valid values in Variable 1) for each date. In other words, I would like to restart labeling rows at each change in date. For example,

```
6/26/2015   1   209.3
6/26/2015   2   230.2
6/26/2015   3   80.4
6/26/2015   4   s2
6/27/2015   1 ....
```

And then I could use the reshape methods described in the other posts.

Edit: This is close to [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format-r), but in order for those answers to fit my data I would need a new column here that assigns a number 1-length variable 1 for each day to the variables, which I don't have.

In other words, if I use

```
data_wide <- reshape(data,direction="wide", idvar = "Date", timevar = "Variable 1")
data_wide
```

Then, because there are 200+ unique entries for Variable 1, data_wide had 200+ columns for each date, with most of those being na because values for Variable 1 typically only exist on a single date in the data, and the data is a time series of over 5000 dates.
~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have a dataframe where column 1 = `Date` and column 2 = `Variable 1` where Variable 1 is usually numeric. E.g.

```
6/26/2015   209.3    
6/26/2015   230.2    
6/26/2015   80.4     
6/26/2015   s2       
6/27/2015   209.1    
6/27/2015   227.2    
6/27/2015   239.2    
6/27/2015   s2
```

I would like to be able to label the rows with a new value that is simply the row number for that date.

```
6/26/2015   209.3    1
6/26/2015   230.2    2
6/26/2015   80.4     3
6/26/2015   s2       4
6/27/2015   209.1    1
6/27/2015   227.2    2
6/27/2015   239.2    3
6/27/2015   s2       4
```

[Original Post]

I have a dataframe where column 1 = `Date` and column 2 = `Variable 1` where Variable 1 is usually numeric. E.g.

```
6/26/2015   209.3
6/26/2015   230.2
6/26/2015   80.4
6/26/2015   s2
6/27/2015   209.1
6/27/2015   227.2
6/27/2015   239.2
6/27/2015   s2
6/28/2015   230.2
6/28/2015   228.2
6/28/2015   36.4
6/28/2015   s2
6/29/2015   209.3
6/29/2015   15.3
6/29/2015   15.4
6/29/2015   s2
```

I would like to be able to "transpose" the data such that each date has its own row, and each Variable for the same date is in the same row. E.g.

```
6/26/2015   209.3     230.2     80.4     s2
6/27/2015   209.1     227.2     239.2    s2
```

And so on. Although this example shows the same number of entries for Variable 1 per date, this is not always the case. I would like to be able to allow for any number of Variables to be collapsed onto the date.

A complicating factor is that there are actually two more columns, Variable 2 and Variable 3, which are constant within a date but may vary between two dates. I would like those to be collapsed onto the date as well, but I only need one column for each of these variables in the new dataframe.

I have tried using dcast and reshape functions, but these do not give the intended result. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshape data from long to wide format R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format-r)

Comment: @jeremycg that is close, except I do not have a column for 'numbers' as that user had. In my case, I would basically need to loop through the dataset and assign each entry for Variable 1 per date a number starting at 1-length(variable 1) per date in order to use that answer.  Your answer also does not address the fact that I do not want to create a new column for every entry of variable 2 and 3 on the same date.

Comment: "a number 1-length variable 1" - this text makes no sense to me.

Comment: I would basically need to loop through the dataset and number the number of Variable 1 entries per date in order to use that answer.

Comment: number the number of a variable?  please try to use programming terms when describing your problem, for instance 'count the number of matching instances for each date'.

Comment: If you want to count the values, then your output example:  `6/26/2015   209.3     230.2     80.4     s2` is wrong.  Please update to show the expected output.  Also the word transpose is not longer appropriate - this is an aggregation operation.

Comment: I want to count them but I don't want to just use the 'counts' value. I would like a new column to label each row with the row number within that date range.

Answer (score 1):

this is best handled via `tapply`: something like

```
tapply(data$`Variable 1`, data$date, c)
```

which creates a ragged array.  The type of a ragged array matches your description of the expected result.  Note that the original order might be lost, but you can restore a sensible order by (e.g.) ordering by date.

you CANNOT (sensibly) transform your result into a legal data frame, because your data type implies a variable number of columns per row.  Data frames are not intended for this use, and if you approach it this way, you will immediately run into more problems.

---

alternatively, what's wrong with the original sparse matrix with lots of NAs?  that's another valid representation of the data type you are discussing.

---

If you are just interested in the count of valid values, just do this:

```
aggregate(data=data,`Variable 1`~Date,length)
```

For the mtcars dataset, this happens:

```
aggregate(data=mtcars,wt~cyl,length)
  cyl wt
1   4 11
2   6  7
3   8 14
```

Note that wt is just a count of values, it doesn't care about the type or value of wt, just how many (length) there are.

Comment: Nothing is 'wrong' with it. What I am trying to do is wind up with a new dataframe that I can use in a time series analysis and it would be GREAT if I could just simply condense the dataframe into a new dataframe where each date has its own row and then 10 columns MAX which have the values in Variable 1.

Comment: okay, I can work with that. please update your problem specification to indicate that you want to have between 1 and 10 valid values, and there will always be 10 columns.  You can't* have multiple columns INSIDE the value of one 'variable' (column) called 'Variable 1'.  Also, please rename your column to something like 'Value1'.  It's not a variable (it's a list index), and using the word variable to describe it is making it difficult to reason about and discuss.  * You can, but please don't.

Comment: If you only want to count the valid values, then please clearly say so.  (That's easy).

Comment: note that reshape2 can do this very well, but since it is fragile I don't care to attempt it without sample data.

Comment: I do not want to simply count the number of valid values, I want to label them (in a new column) as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and restart when the date changes.

Answer (score 0):

This solution takes a dataframe where column 1 contains date values which are repeated for several rows, and where column 2 contains a value for each row. The goal is to have a new dataframe where column 1 contains no repeat dates, and each row (date) contains all of the values listed in column 2, essentially condensing dates and transposing column 2 into the date. To do this with reshape, first, each value for the same date needs a number.

```
   require(data.table)
      dt <- data.table(dataframe)
      newdt<-dt[, number := 1:.N, by = Date] 
      data<-as.data.frame(newdt)

    data_wide <- reshape(newdt, direction="wide", idvar = "Date", timevar =   "number")

    data_wide

    6/26/2015   209.3     230.2     80.4     s2
    6/27/2015   209.1     227.2     239.2    s2
```